# HP LaserJet printer installation failed

Tags: windows-10, printer, hp

this seems to have been caused by some of the MS updates. Printer stopped printing. Unfortunately those guides advising me to check if there is another "copy of" printer don't apply as there was no such other printer. I have tried reinstalling it, but running the HPsetup seems to be fine at first and detects the printer on a USB port, but in the end it says "printer installation failed" and no reason.
[image]

It's a Dell desktop PC with Windows 10 and the printer is HP LaserJet P1102. I tried also manually installing the printer via print manager console by doing add printer - choose driver from disk - choose the C:\LJP1100_P1560_P1600_Full_Solution folder which appeared during HPsetup full driver install and there I chose existing USB001 local port. Printer gets installed, but test page doesn't go and it doesn't react. Ideas?
[image]

Comment: Delete the printer (Devices and Printers), uninstall the Printer Driver (Programs and Features), Restart.  Now try installing in Devices and Printers with just the Windows driver. This often works.

Comment: did the Windows Printer work?

Comment: Deleting the printer is not sufficient. You also need to remove the driver files by clicking on Print Server Properties > Drivers, and removing the printer there.

Answer (score 0):

right click p1102 driver and select properties
click on compatibility tab
tick the box next to windows 7 mode
click ok
now run the driver exe file and it will install drivers
and printer will run

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please see the [answering guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), then please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778322/edit) your question accordingly, preferably using punctuation, capitalization etc. to improve readability. Please check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), Asking and Answering in the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help) and some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how SE sites work. These aren't discussion forums but Q&A sites, so they work a bit differently.

Comment: interesting idea!